# How to detect which object mapper is used in deserializing my response?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have a strange problem.  I'd like to control the deserialization of my response and, normally, the following works just fine:

```
spring:
jackson:
   default-property-inclusion: non-empty
```

However, the moment I include an external library that I created myself (and that, in turns, includes other dependencies) in my pom.xml, it seems that the previous property is overwritten! The response starts showing null and empty fields.

Is there a way to debug what's happening?  I though that the property I used overrode every object mapper defined but that doesn't seem to be the case!

Comment: What is the name of this library you included to a project? Which version of `Jackson` and `Spring Boot` do you use?

Comment: Unortunately it's a jar created by me that includes other dependencies :( I'm with spring boot 2.2.5

Comment: Does it contains any extra configuration or `ObjectMapper` instances, or `Jackson` modules which could change the way how objects are serialised to `JSON`? When you try to remove this dependence all start to work as before and `non-empty` works properly, does it?

Comment: Found it! I wanted to define a custom object mapper but, even though I put a qualifier, it was registered as spring's default one. So, doesn't matter the qualifier it still gets subistituted?

Comment: Mostly it depends from configuration you have created. I would have to see all config files to say definitely what happened. Also, you can turn on logging level on `DEBUG` for `Spring` and check which beans where created and when. Also find `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and check how it works. `ObjectMapper` can be created by `Spring Boot` or by clients code. Take a look on documentation: [4.3. Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)